# How to get the colour of text in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

Given that I am not using a proper stylesheet/style, is there a way of making the colour selector the same colour as an another existing word?

I can copy and paste the texts to keep the colour, but I just want to make other text the same colour?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, use the format painter.

1. Select the text you want to copy the formatting from
2. Click on the "format painter" button. It looks like a yellow paintbrush. In 2003 it is just to the left of undo. In 2007 it is on the "Home" tab toward the left side of the ribbon.

[image: image description]

3. Drag through any text you want to see in the same color.

Notes: It doesn't just do color. It does all formatting

If you want to apply the formatting to multiple pieces of text, double click the format painter button instead of single clicking and you can apply it as much as you want. When you are done, just de-select the painter or hit the "escape" key

Comment: "Notes: It doesn't just do color. It does all formatting" - precisely why this not a suitable answer IMHO.  Let's just say, I landed here searching for a way to copy the color only and I know the format painter well enough.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to actually find the RGB colour of the text rather than just copying it then:

1. Select the text you're interested in
2. Right click on the text and choose Font from the context menu (or just hit ctrl-D)
3. Click the down arrow to the right of the Font color setting, then click More Colors
4. Click the Custom tab, and you'll see the RGB value of the colour.

Answer (score 0):

Slight difference if you are using Word for Mac version 16.27, you

1. Select the text you're interested in.
2. Right click (or two-finger tap) on the text.
3. Select Font.
4. In the Font dialog box, click the down arrow 
   to the right of Font color.
5. Click on More Colors.

---- Here's where it gets a little different ----

6. Choose the icon for RGB Sliders or the RGB 
   Sliders drop-down menu item. You'll see the 
   RGB values for the color.
7. Click OK, and the color will become one of the
   Recent Colors choices in your text color menu.